# Is a connected iOS device required for a successful build in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to Xcode and my first project is a simple iOS 8 app with a *Share Extension* target. I noticed that files are marked in red (missing) if I select `>Product >Build`. 
If I do the same thing but with a connected device they went from red to black and the build is successful.  Why do I need to connect a device to get a successful build?

Answer (score 0):

@Matt, It depends on what profile your building for.  I'll attach image of the current build profiles I have selected in Xcode 6.1.[image: xcode build profiles]  But basically if you target a simulator, your gonna want to click the play button, and then your project will be copied to the simulator you selected, and then launched.  When I build my app for my device, then I select `>Product >Build` because I don't have an Apple developer's license, but it still builds a `MyApp.app` binary / executable project in the Derived Data location specified your preferences.  I hope my answer helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need an iDevice to develop for iOS. Even though it is a better solution than the simulator since you will see how it actually is especially regarding performance and speed.

You can ignore the red marked files as long as the app still runs properly on the Simulator / Device.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You could safely archive and deploy app without real device. Just selecting iOS device will enable Archive option.

Comment: oh really? even though there is no device attached?